# Creating an object in a forEach loop and pushing it onto an array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm creating objects in a forEach loop. I'm attempting to count the number of tweets on a given day, add those values up for that day, and push the day/count object back onto an array.

My desired result is something like this:

```
[
  { 
    "date": "April 5th", 
    "tweets": 12
  },
  { 
    "date": "April 4th", 
    "tweets": 20
  }
]
```

The code I have:

```
App.TweetsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  tweetFrequencies: function() {
    var self = this;
    var model = self.get('model');
    var tweetsHash = {};
    var tweetsArray = [];

    model.forEach(function(item) {

      var tweetFreq = {};
      var normalizedDate = moment(item.created_at).format( 'MMMM Do' );

      if ( tweetsHash[normalizedDate] === undefined ) {
        tweetsHash[normalizedDate] = { "Date": normalizedDate, "Tweets": 1 };
      } else {
        tweetsHash[normalizedDate]["Tweets"] += 1;
      }

      tweetFreq['tdate'] = tweetsHash[normalizedDate]["Date"];
      tweetFreq['tweets'] = tweetsHash[normalizedDate]["Tweets"];
      tweetsArray.push( tweetFreq );

    });

    return tweetsArray;

  }.property('model')
});
```

Edit:

[image: Data I'm getting back]

Comment: So what's the problem? Looks like you have your desired result, no?

Comment: @thomas I only wanted the object once all of the tweets for a given day were counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accidentally injecting a new object every time.  You can use your existing condition of when the item doesn't exist yet and only insert then.

```
App.TweetsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  tweetFrequencies: function() {
    var self = this,
        model = this.get('model'),
        tweetsHash = {},
        tweetsArray = [];

    model.forEach(function(item) {

      var normalizedDate = moment(item.created_at).format( 'MMMM Do' );

      if ( tweetsHash[normalizedDate] === undefined ) {
        tweetsHash[normalizedDate] = { "Date": normalizedDate, "Tweets": 1 };
        tweetsArray.push( tweetsHash[normalizedDate] );
      } else {
        tweetsHash[normalizedDate]["Tweets"] += 1;
      }

    });

    return tweetsArray;

  }.property('model')
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that you only need to do the initial push if the object doesn't exist and then keep iterating.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your tweetFreq object is identical to your tweetsHash... why not:

```
model.forEach(function(item) {

  var normalizedDate = moment(item.created_at).format( 'MMMM Do' );

  if ( tweetsHash[normalizedDate] === undefined ) {
    tweetsHash[normalizedDate] = { "Tweets": 1 };
  } else {
    tweetsHash[normalizedDate]["Tweets"] += 1;
  }

});

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(tweetsHash).length; i++) {
  var date = Object.keys(tweetsHash)[i];
  tweetsArray.push({"Date": date, "Tweets": tweetsHash[date]["Tweets"]});
}

return tweetsArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to do two things at once.  I separated them below... I'm still not sure why you don't do them in one step and modify the final array in the first loop get rid of the hash variable.  There may be a reason as it relates to code you are not showing us... so I'll leave it like this:

```
 model.forEach(function(item) {
      var normalizedDate = moment(item.created_at).format( 'MMMM Do' );

      if ( tweetsHash[normalizedDate] === undefined ) {
        tweetsHash[normalizedDate] = { "Date": normalizedDate, "Tweets": 1 };
      } else {
        tweetsHash[normalizedDate]["Tweets"] += 1;
      }
 });

 tweetsHash.forEach(function(item) {
      var tweetFreq = {};

      tweetFreq['tdate'] = item["Date"];
      tweetFreq['tweets'] = item["Tweets"];

      tweetsArray.push( tweetFreq );
 });

 return tweetsArray;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works because the tweetsHash isn't an array but an object so you can't do a forEach loop over it (as far as I know). I do like the approach of separating it out into a separate function though!